# some trouble with yield in ruby

Tags: ruby, yield

I run a simple function:

```
def test 
   a = 10
   yield a
   puts a
end

test { |x| x += 10 }
```

and get an unexpected answer

```
> 10
```

Next, I tried to reuse the function this way:

```
def test 
   a = 10
   a = yield a
   puts a
end
```

the result is

```
 > 20
```

But I find this code ugly and not in ruby-style, how can i improve it?

Comment: Passing `test { |x| x += 10 }` to `def test; a = 10; yield a; puts a; end` evaluates to `def test; a = 10; 20; puts a; end`.  You can see that `a` is not altered by that.  Yes, Ruby is sometimes a little homely in appearance, but beautiful none the less.  Your second try is very much in the "Ruby style".

Comment: The only thing I'd change is the block itself: `{ |x| x + 10 }`

Answer (score 3):

### The theory:

In ruby, everything is a reference. What does it mean? Every bit of data you use (like number 10 or string 'hello world') are created somewhere in memory. And all the variables (which are also placed in memory) simply points to the memory location those object occupies.

There are two types of objects - mutable and immutable. Mutable objects can be modified, i.e. if we have a string 'hello' placed in memory, we can modify it without changing his location in memory, so all other variables pointing at its location will yield changed value as well. Example:

```
a = b = 'hello'
a[2] = 'b'

a   #=> 'heblo'
b   #=> 'heblo'
```

So you have created 'hello' string object in memory and pointed variables a and b to its memory location. Now if you modify it, since both variables are pointing to the same location, both variables seems to be changed. However assingment of the new value

```
a = 'foo'
b #=> 'heblo'
```

is not modifying the object. It is rather creating a new object in the memory and pointing variable b to this object's memory location. Also note that:

```
a = 'foo'
b = 'foo'
```

will create two separate objects in the memory, and variables a and b are pointing to different locations.

Immutable objects cannot be modified and cannot be duplicated. This means there is always at most one location in the memory representing given object. For example, all Fixnums are immutable (also nil, false, true and symbols). Hence this code:

```
a = 1
b = 1
```

will make both variables to point at the same location in the memory. It doesn't really matter, because object stored there cannot be modified anyway.

### Your problem:

So what happens when you yielding a variable into a block. The new variable is created to point to the same location in the memory. Since you are yielding a fixnum, whcih is immutable, it cannot be modified. So `x += 10' actually repoints the new local variable x, to different location in memory, hence the original x is not changed.

It would look different if you pass a string and modify it:

```
def test
  a = 'foo'
  yield a
  puts a
end

test { a.replace 'bar' }

# Output: 'bar'
```

Note the `replace` method which modifies string without repointing memory pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Say you had this function:

```
def test(x)
  x += 10
end
```

If I had:

```
a = 10
test(a)
```

`a` would not change. So in your example, `a` would still be 10 after the block executes.

If anything, you can do:

```
def test 
   puts yield 10
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruby, like almost all modern languages, is pass-by-value. You cannot mutate variable bindings from the caller's scope.